# Appium switch application is not working

Tags: android, appium, robotframework

Here is the log

> Test Andriod Demo :: App for appium library
>
> OpenApplication1
>   | PASS |
>   OpenApplication2
>   | FAIL | URLError: 
>   SwitchApplication1
>   | FAIL | Variable '${browser}' not found.

Here is the Test case

```
OpenApplication1
    ${browser}  Open Application  http://localhost:4723/wd/hub  platformName=Android  platformVersion=4.2.2  deviceName=192.168.56.101:5555  app=${CURDIR}/demoapp/Browser.apk  automationName=appium  appPackage=com.app.robot  appActivity=MainActivity
OpenApplication2    
    ${app}  Open Application  http://localhost:4725/wd/hub  platformName=Android  platformVersion=4.2.2  deviceName=192.168.56.101:5555  app=${CURDIR}/demoapp/QA.apk  automationName=appium  appPackage=com.app.test  appActivity=LoginActivity
SwitchApplication1
    Switch Application   ${browser}
```

Sincerely looking for an answer

Comment: What is your question, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I am having two apps and I should be able to switch between them.

Comment: @Cleb - Isn't there any way to simulataneously run test case ?

Comment: @Manju - Testcase can not run simultaneously but it will run one by one

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by closing the first application and opening the second application.

use this below command

```
   OpenApplication1
```

do some activities with that then close the application

```
   Close Application
   OpenApplication2
```

Comment: I will check and tell u

Comment: This is ok and solving the problem partially but after closing we can not  start from where it is left off before.. any way one upvote for suggestion

Answer (score 1):

While the first application is running you can launch second application but you have to kill the second application to come back where you left off in the first application

```
OpenApplication2 

./adb shell monkey -p com.test.t1 -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1

CloseApplication2

./adb shell am force-stop com.test.t1
```

FYI:

- *adb* -> To connect with the device
- *shell* -> To make use of terminal or command prompt
- *am* -> Activity Manager
- *monkey* ->  The Monkey is a program that runs on your emulator or device and generates pseudo-random streams of user events such as clicks, touches, or gestures, as well as a number of system-level events. You can use the Monkey to stress-test applications that you are developing, in a random yet repeatable manner.

use the keyword `execute` to run adb

Answer (score 0):

I also have tried like you But
Switch application is not implemented as of now in Appium for Robot Framework

Answer (score 0):

A workaround worked for me. Try this.

```
 OpenApplication1
 OpenApplication2
 Switch Application ${browser}
 Background App 5
```

After last keyword, it will switch to Application1

Comment: why did you use `Background App 5` ? What it does here ? can you please elaborate ?

Comment: Can you please explain me ${browser} ? Thanks